# Referencing a flatDir from library module

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My project contains one main module ('app') and one library module ('mylibrary'). In my library I have a libs folder, which contains an aar file to a library that I want to use in my 'library' module.
I'm referencing my aar library using the following gradle script:

```
repositories{
   flatDir{
     dirs 'libs'
   }
}

dependencies{
   compile(name:'nameOfAar', ext:'aar')
}
```

This doesn't help it's trying to look in the mavenCentral for the aar library, but doesn't want to look in the flat directory that I've specified. Does anybody got any clue, how can I reference an aar library from an library module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem but unfortunately the only solution that I found is to add `'../<library_dir>/libs'` to build.gradle of the app

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs', '../<library_dir>/libs'
    }
}
```

Comment: But does this means that if I compile my library module, and use it in some other app, I will have to reference the aar manually and it won't be built in to this library module?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately if you want to use in other apps you should reference the aar manually

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I will mark your answer as the most appropriate for this case.

Comment: Thank you , but I really want to know the official solution.